# Set background in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe

I waned to put a background in a JFrame, so I searched on YouTube and found a Video, but it didn't work I tried another one and this didn't work either so what is wrong with my code
because all the time i start it is just not there but eclipse dont mark anything wrong.

```
package Pack;




import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui {

    public Gui(){
        JLabel background;
          Var.jf = new JFrame(); 
           Var.jf.setSize(Var.screenwidth, Var.screenheight);
           Var.jf.setTitle("test");
           Var.jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           Var.jf.setResizable(false);
           Var.jf.setVisible(true);
           Var.jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
           Var.jf.setLayout(null);
          ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("Bilder/Testbild");
         
          background =  new JLabel("",img,JLabel.CENTER);
          background.setBounds(0,0,1000,1000);
         
          Var.jf.add(background);
           
           Var.Buttonxstart = new JButton("Start");
           Var.Buttonxstart.setBounds(300,220,400,120);
           Var.jf.add(Var.Buttonxstart);
         
           Var.Buttonxclose = new JButton("Exit");
           Var.Buttonxclose.setBounds(300,440,400,120);
           Var.jf.add(Var.Buttonxclose);
          
           
           
           
        
    }
    
    
}
```

.

```
package Pack;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

  public class Var {
  static JFrame jf;
  static int screenheight = 1000;
  static int screenwidth = 1000;
  static JButton Buttonxstart;
  static JButton Buttonxclose;
 
  
  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points:

1. code should check if the image is really being loaded - `ImageIcon` does not throw any Exception if the file is not found. Test if the height or width is `-1` or not, example:

```
if (img.getIconHeigth() == -1) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("image: Bilder/Testbild");
}
```

or better IMO, use `ImageIO.read()`.

2. the whole GUI code should run in the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread), see [Swing's Threading Policy.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading) . Unable to see if it is, if not, use some code like `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Gui());`

<sup>3. it is not recommended to use the `null` layout manager.Check the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) tutorial.</sup>

Note: I tested the posted code - it's working, if calling `new Gui()` on the EDT and having an image `Testbild` in folder `Bilder`. But for background image I would prefer to override the `paintComponent` method of a `JPanel`, to paint the image.

Comment: In Swing you should be using `revalidate()`, not validate(). However, there is no need for either method. The frame should be made visible AFTER all components are added to the  frame.